# How to get value from a list of a specific column using comma separated string

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-boot, email

I want to send email to multiple people and want to get those emails from list of email recipients.

```
{
  "webId": 1001,
  "externalKey": null,
  "fromEmail": "test@gmail.com",
  "fromName": "TEST",
  "subject": "hello",
  "body": "This is a test mail",
  "status": 1,
  "sentDate": null,
  "sendAttempts": 1,
  "permanentFailure": false,
  "emailRecipientModel": [
  {
    "webId": 1101,
    "emailId": 1001,
    "emailAddress": "tets1@gmail.com",
    "status": "PENDING",
    "smtpStatusCode": 123,
    "recipientType": "TO"
  },
  {
    "webId": 1102,
    "emailId": 1001,
    "emailAddress": "test2@gmail.com",
    "status": "PENDING",
    "smtpStatusCode": 123,
    "recipientType": "TO"
  }
  ],
 }
```

Now I want to get the email address of both email recipients.

In my model class of email. I have a list of emailRecipients.

Now How to get the email addresses or all the email recipients.

This is the function where i am sending email.

```
MimeMessage message = javaMailSender.createMimeMessage();
MimeMessageHelper helper = new MimeMessageHelper(message,true);
helper.setFrom(email.getFromEmail());
helper.setTo(email.getEmailRecipient().);      // need to add all the recipients here using comma separated list
helper.setSubject(email.getSubject());
helper.setText(email.getBody());
        
javaMailSender.send(message);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
MimeMessage message = javaMailSender.createMimeMessage();
MimeMessageHelper helper = new MimeMessageHelper(message,true);
helper.setFrom(email.getFromEmail());

String recipients = email.getEmailRecipient().stream()
                                   .map(e -> e.getEmailAddress())
                                   .collect( Collectors.joining( "," ) );

helper.setTo(recipients);   
helper.setSubject(email.getSubject());
helper.setText(email.getBody());
        
javaMailSender.send(message);
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your method `email.getEmailRecipient()` returns a list of strings you can do something like

```
helper.setTo(email.getEmailRecipient().stream().toArray(String[]::new));
```

or

```
helper.setTo(email.getEmailRecipient().toArray(new String[0]));
```

Comment: email.getEmailRecipient() returns the whole array or list.